# Strapi - Unable to "Add Content Type"

Tags: strapi

When I click on, I just have blanck page at the url http://localhost:1337/admin/plugins/content-type-builder/#create::contentType::baseSettings
I use the v3.0.0-alpha.14.3 version.
Node version v8.12.0
NPM version 6.4.1
I use MongoDB.
I have this errors in Chrome console

```
main.js:16 Error: Minified React error #188; visit 
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=188 for the full 
message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and 
additional helpful warnings. 
at r (main.js:11)
at o (main.js:11)
at Ie (main.js:11)
at Fe (main.js:11)
at Object.findDOMNode (main.js:19)
at t.updateStatus (main.js:32)
at t.componentDidMount (main.js:32)
at tn (main.js:16)
at en (main.js:16)
at Qo (main.js:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. I solved it by running

`npm run setup`

Hope this helps !